# vb .net passing objects/variables through classes

Tags: vb.net

I'm struggling with the solution of passing the variables through different classes in VB.
The goal is to  run a Form to present the progress and other info (I made a BackgroundWorker inside Form1), while a different vb thread is doing the job.
I finished with the MainClass and myWrapper, which does not do the job in the Form1 window. I set the class WorkerArgs between them, to pass the arguments, but I can only create 2 different objects of WorkerArgs. 
I need to pass the same WorkerArgs.startProgress value to Form1 Class... How to do it?

```
Public Class MainClass
   Shared Sub Main()
    Dim form1 As Form = New Form1
    Dim myWrapper As WorkerArgs = New WorkerArgs
    form1.Show()
        
    myWrapper.startProgress = "start"

   End Sub

End Class

Public Class WorkerArgs
    Public startProgress As String
    Public passPercentage As String
End Class

Public Class Form1
    
    Public Sub OnLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim args As WorkerArgs
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(args)
    End Sub
    
    
    Public Sub bgw1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        ' Access variables through e
        Dim args As WorkerArgs = e.Argument
        ' Do something with args
        Dim str As String = args.startProgress
        If str = "start" Then
            MessageBox.Show(str)
        End If
    End Sub
[...]
End Class
```

Comment: The BackgroundWorker class has a method `ReporProgress(int, object)` designed to report progress and a user state which should excatly do what you want. See this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: I really don't know how to pass the value from the MainClass to a method ReportProgress()

Comment: it is just like I can operate ReportProgress() inside Form1, but not from the outer class

Comment: Yes that is what it supposed to be used. You report progress from within the background worker. I don´t get what you want to achieve there. How should an outer object know soemthing about the prgoress of a backrground worker instead of the bgw itself?

Comment: Do you just want the WorkerArgs created in MainClass also in Form1?

Comment: yes, I want to pass the progress 0-100 and the text message what is currently under calculations. So everything is going on in the MainClass, Form 1 is just a side thread

Comment: `Form 1 is just a side thread` . Is this a winforms project? In that cas Forms1 runs on the main thread, You just have to call the `ReportProgress` and handle the `ProgressChanged` event. If you want to do something with the values in the MainClass create puplic properties in it and call it from form1 or set an ManClass field in Form1 before form1.Load or...

Comment: could you find a solution for your problem?